# Fetch with 'If-None-Match': "etag" header always returning 200 in React Native app

Tags: react-native, fetch, etag

I'm encountering a very strange issue in a react native app where a simple fetch with an etag is always returning a `200` rather than an expected `304`:

```
const response = await fetch(url, {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'If-None-Match': etag
  },
});
```

where `etag` is something like `"33a64df551425fcc55e4d42a148795d9f25f89d4"`

When I make this request directly through something like Postman/Insomnia, it is working and I get the appropriate `304` response.

Inspecting the app in Reactotron, I can see the network request header seems to be correct:

[image: Reactotron screenshot]

If I copy the JSON request as cURL I get the following:

> curl -H "if-none-match:"33a64df551425fcc55e4d42a148795d9f25f89d4"" https://url/to/api

With a slight modification to show only the headers:

> curl -sD - -o /dev/null -H "if-none-match:"33a64df551425fcc55e4d42a148795d9f25f89d4"" https://url/to/api

Which also only returns a `200`, but if I escape the quotes around the etag like so, it works:

> curl -sD - -o /dev/null -H "if-none-match:\"33a64df551425fcc55e4d42a148795d9f25f89d4\"" https://url/to/api

I'm genuinely confused because I've tried all variants of:

```
'If-None-Match': etag
'If-None-Match': `"${etag}"`
'If-None-Match': `\"${etag}\"`
'If-None-Match': '"' + etag + '"'
```

to no avail, what am I doing wrong?

Putting the same fetch request into an html file and testing in the browser works with the expected `304` status.

Answer (score 2):

Under the hood, React Native is using NSURLCache which returns a 200 even when it receives a 304 from upstream, at least from what I’ve read online. Have a look using Charles Web Proxy or another such proxy from the App Store and you’ll see the traffic over the network before it hits your app. Googling reveals a lot of edge cases around caching also, such as apparently not caching private responses by default.

Comment: In my case I had to put a `Cache-control: max-age=0` header in my request, in order to make iOS actually validate the stored value with the server, using the Etag, otherwise it would just use the cache value without requesting the server, for a while after the first response.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the same issue using Axios on a React Native App. I also tried the opposite 'If-Match' and getting 200, so it's as if the header is not even there.

```js
const query = {
  method: 'GET',
  url: `someurl`,
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    'If-Match': etag,
  },
};

let response = await axios(query);
```